# Can I bring the lock screen back after dismissing it? ('go back a screen' from password entry)

Tags: windows-8, lock-screen

As we all know, there is a clock on the lock screen. And the lock screen (with clock) disappears when we click to go type a password.

Can I show the lock screen (or at least the clock) from the password entry screen, without logging in and locking it again? Is there some keyboard shortcut or gesture that does this?

Comment: Couldn't find it. :(

Comment: I switched to the lock screen and pressed **literally every combination of keys** and still couldn't find anything. I discovered a couple of other interesting shortcuts though (and pushing [Shift] five times turns on Sticky Keys :P).

Comment: Leave the screen idle for a while or press the power button (provided you have not set your power button action to shutdown or restart your computer)

Comment: trying to drag it down from the top doesn't work either

Comment: @AbhishekGirish Power button does not work (set to `Do Nothing`, other options are `Sleep` and `Shut Down` anyway). I guess idle would work, but do you know how long the timer is, or if it can be decreased? May as well log in & lock, I guess.

Comment: Power button worked for me. So did setting the screen saver to 1 min (you cannot set it to less than a minute)

Comment: I'm curious what your end goal is? The login screen will disappear after a short while and 'waking up' the monitor after that (moving mouse, etc.) will show the lock screen again with the clock. So what are you trying to achieve with customizing the lock screen?

Comment: @Mufasa My goal is to show the lock screen on demand. Say I have the background set to a classes timetable, and I accidentally skip it when waking the computer up. It would simply be *convenient* to be able to show it again (my rather long password doesn't help matters...).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There does not appear to be any way to do this with the default login settings. Pressing <kbd>esc</kbd> does nothing.

However, if you turn on the option to require pressing Ctrl+Alt+Del to log in, then pressing <kbd>esc</kbd> will work, as well as hitting the "back" arrow on the login page.

To require Ctrl+Alt+Del for login, go to the run dialog (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) and type in `control userpasswords2`. Switch to the "advanced" tab and check "Require users to press Ctrl+Alt+Delete".

[image: ctrl alt del options]

The locked screen will look the same is normal (clock, pretty picture, and all) but instead of being able to press any key to unlock, you must enter Ctrl+Alt+Del.

Comment: Perfect! There's a nice little back arrow, too. Now why couldn't they add that behavior to the default? Silly MS. :\

Comment: By default, the back arrow goes to the switch users screen, so I guess they think it would be confusing. What would make sense is if once you were on the switch users screen, you could then hit the back arrow _again_ to go back to the lock screen.

Comment: I only have one user, so there is no switch users screen for me. But I'll take your word for it (no back arrow in default view for me).

Comment: This solution no longer works with the current build of Windows 10