# How to get back to Lock Screen from Password screen in Microsoft Surface?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-surface, windows-rt

Similar to this question: [Can I bring the lock screen back after dismissing it? ('go back a screen' from password entry)](https://superuser.com/questions/493725/can-i-bring-the-lock-screen-back-after-dismissing-it-go-back-a-screen-from-p)

How do I go back to the Lock Screen once I've gone to the password screen in Microsoft Surface tablet?

This is a different mechanism from using the referenced question in that no physical keyboard is available.

Alternately, can the timeout on the password screen be shortened?

**Edit**

At this point I would like to change the timeout of the password screen. Can this be done, either through GUI or registry (or other) means?

Comment: Just curious, but why? Also, you can just use the power button on your surface or leave it idle.

Comment: Just want to see the time. Not thinking, I slid up to password screen and then couldn't get back. Timeout works, but don't want to wait. Hitting power button twice brings back to password screen - I suspect that the timeout is the same as for password timeout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was possible with windows 7 using <kbd>ESC</kbd> or <kbd>WIN</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>, but in windows 8 that doesn't work anymore.

So, no, although it can be very annoying, you can't do that.

**EDIT**

To answer your edit, it is possible to change the timeout from the default 1 minute:

1. Make sure the the [Console lock display off timeout](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/8267-power-options-add-console-lock-display-off-timeout-windows-8-a.html) option is added to Advanced Power Settings
2. Open your Advanced Power Settings, and select Console lock display off timeout
3. Set the new timeout

[image: Power options panel]

Source: [eightforums.com](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/8268-lock-screen-timeout-period-change-windows-8-a.html)

Here is the registry key needed to add the timeout option:

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings\7516b95f-f776-4464-8c53-06167f40cc99\8EC4B3A5-6868-48c2-BE75-4F3044BE88A7]

"Attributes"=dword:00000002

Comment: This question is specific to tablets (i.e., no keyboard).

Comment: @GaTechThomas I know, I was just listing how it could be done *before* windows 8 - now it cannot be done, both on tablets and desktop

Comment: Ugh, can't go below 1 minute.